# How to concatenate variables in AS3 for flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a function which ideally you tell it to go to the next level and it sorts everything out to transition to the next level for you.  Currently I use this to get from level 1 to 2...

```
level1.GoButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClick);

function myClick(eventObject:MouseEvent) {

    if (levelText == "Password"){
        //mc level transition
        removeChild(level1);
        var level2 = new level_2();
        addChild(level2);
        //bring effects to top
        setChildIndex(screen_FX, numChildren - 1);
        //bring border to top
        setChildIndex(Border, numChildren - 1);
        //diable layer mask mouse
        level2.masking.mouseEnabled = false;
        //play mc and transition effects
        level2.gotoAndPlay(1);

        } else {

            wrong.play(0, 1);

        }
}
```

I was thinking if somehow you can pass into a function a variable which could concatenate variable names, for example

```
    removeChild(level[i]);
    var level[i+1] = new level_[i+1}();
    addChild(level[i+1});
```

Also I need to make it so it checks if levelText == whatever on press of the Enter key, as well as the mouse click on GoButton.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proper way of doing this:

```
removeChild(getChildByName("level" + i.toString()));
var levelClassName:String = "level_" + (i+1).toString();
var levelClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(levelClassName);
var level:DisplayObject = new levelClass();
level.name = "level" + (i+1).toString();
addChild(level);
```

You don't need to change your variable name since it's local and won't exist on the next execution of `myClick`.

Comment: Is there something you don't like with this?

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted your answer Kodiak because it helped me solve my issue after hours of looking for the right way to do this very thing. Thank you so much! However, while using your code I came across a few errors (at least Flash CS5 didn't like a couple of things you had done). So if anyone else happens to come across this, here is what I had to do in order to get this to work in Flash.

```
    removeChild(getChildByName("level" + i.toString()));
    var levelClassName:String = "level_" + (i+1).toString();
    var levelClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(levelClassName) as Class;
    var level:DisplayObject = new levelClass;
    level.name = "level" + (i+1).toString();
    addChild(level);
```

The difference is really just some syntax, but it caused errors. Specifically, the getDefinitionByName did not need to be retyped as a String (nor can it be it seems via ':String' maybe 'as String' or something might be better if it's even needed??). Also it gave a mismatch error between an object and a class, so I had to add the 'as Class' to the line as well. The other spot that kicked back some errors was just the 'levelClass:Class'. I found that it doesn't need to be typed at all, but again ':Class' was not liked by the compiler. I believe this is only for typing variables as in 'var levelClass:Class' otherwise you have to type things with 'levelClass as Class' or 'Class(levelClass)'. I am a coding noob here so there is a good chance I'm wrong about that, but in any event, this is the code I had to use in order to make this work. Also don't forget to 'import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;' into your package.